.NET 8 Httpclient post parameter changing it's case to camel
I have a strange issue using IhttpClientFactory named client. 
The "POST" body parameter are changing it's case to camel "initCap". I have written some Handlers (delegate handler) for adding "http headers", "exception handling" and "audit logging".  The parameters are changing the case to camelcase.
My Model class
 public class PostRequest
 {
    [DataMember(Name = "Request", EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public Request? Request { get; set; }
 }

I know that the attribute is for Newtonsof json but tried JsonProperty as well but not working.
.....
to get the response of the post call (inside a generic calss method
var httpContent = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(resource, requestBody, cancellationToken);
return await httpContent.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<T>(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);

Anyone faced similar issue?

What is initCap?

@GuruStron the property is first letter capital as "Request" but in httpclient request it's changing to "request" initial letter to small.

@GuruStron it was working well in .Net 6. I doubting there is something to do with the default sterilizer with HttpClient which is "System.Text.Json".

TBH not sure how it was working with .NET 6. Try the options I have suggested in the answer.

PostAsJsonAsync uses JsonSerializerDefaults.Web for serializer options by default which will result in Camel case property names and data contracts (DataMemeberAttribute) are not supported by System.Text.Json. If you want use another set of settings for serialization (i.e. Pascal case default serialization) - you can provide them. For example:
var httpContent = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(
    resource, 
    requestBody,
    new JsonSerializerOptions(), // TODO: configure as needed and reuse the options
    cancellationToken);

Or use the JsonPropertyNameAttribute (will need to mark all properties which require "non-default" handling). For example:
public class PostRequest
{
    [JsonPropertyName("Request")] // should be Pascal case no matter which System.Text.Json settings used
    public Request? Request { get; set; } 
}

See also:

How to customize property names and values with System.Text.Json
CA1869: Cache and reuse 'JsonSerializerOptions' instances


Don't create a new JsonSerializerOptions for every request - creating new instances of JsonSerializerOptions is expensive and can lead to performance issues. Either use JsonSerializerOptions.Default, resolve it from your dependency injection container, or create a static shared instance and re-use it across requests.

you need to add attribute "serialize" if you want to change form Actual . So if your property is "Request" and you want to change it to something else like "request" then you only need to do that isn't it? The default should be changed.

Here is a reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/customize-properties?pivots=dotnet-6-0#customize-individual-property-names

@शेखर TBH not following your question. "Here is a reference" - yes it is the same one which is present in the answer in the "See also".

@GuruStron it should not change to lowerCase default. That's my point it for reference I provided the link

@शेखर what should not change to "lowerCase" and why? And why do you think the link is proof for that?

Why you request parameter should change it's case. Unless there is some configuration is done for it. the link you can see the Property Name "TemperatureCelsius" and when sterilize it's still the same "TemperatureCelsius" not changed it's case to "temperatureCelsius"

@शेखर that is covered in the first sentence of the answer - "PostAsJsonAsync uses JsonSerializerDefaults.Web", so the default casing is Camel case. If you will serialize with JsonSerializer.Serialize you will get the expected JSON. Or if you change from JsonSerializerDefaults.Web by providing "custom"  JsonSerializerOptions to the PostAsJsonAsync.
